# What are the Minimum Requirements for a Quroum node?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, raspberry-pi

I am planning to run a [Quorum](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum) (Ethereum fork) blockchain on my business. I was wondering if quorum node will run on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

Raspberri Specs:

- Broadcom BCM2837B0, Cortex-A53 (ARMv8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.4GHz
- 1GB LPDDR2 SDRAM
- Raspbian Stretch (Debian version 9)
- 64GB Micro SD (should be enough I guess)

Comment: We haven't tested such a setup, but afaik, it should run fine. There are some steeper requirements for Tessera (Java Private Transaction Manager), but Constellation may work.